# ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY b). Perfomance when used in conjunction with "WITH AS" and "WHERE" to limit the result?

Tags: mysql, sql

Our table is named "products".

We would like to get, from each "productLine" 3 products of the highest "quantityInStock".

This query works and it is a generally accepted approach:

```
WITH inventory
AS (SELECT 
       productLine,
       productName,
       quantityInStock,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          PARTITION BY productLine 
          ORDER BY quantityInStock DESC) row_num
    FROM 
       products
   )
SELECT 
   productLine,
   productName,
   quantityInStock
FROM 
   inventory
WHERE 
   row_num <= 3;
```

I am in doubt as to whether the above example would be fast with a multi million or billion rows table.
It looks like it will go through the whole table before it limits the result into WHERE row_num <= 3;

If the above technique is slow for big tables, is there any better approach?

I am using MySQL 8+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, any question on performance needs to be tested on your data and in your environment.

Second, the row number needs to assign a value to *all* rows.  It should use an index, if available, so it should have reasonable performance.

Performance on such queries is tricky, if you consider the extremes:

- One product line over the entire table, so the result set has three rows.
- A different product line on each row, so the rest set is the entire table.

However, with the right indexes, it is possible that a correlated subquery will be faster under many reasonable conditions -- particularly when there are relatively few product lines:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
WHERE p.quantityInStock <= (SELECT p2.quantityInStock
                            FROM products p2
                            WHERE p2.productline = p.productline
                            ORDER BY p2.quantityInStock DESC
                            LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
                           );
```

The correct index is on `products(productline, quantityInStock desc)`.

Note:  The above assumes that each "product line" has at least three products.  It also assumes that the quantities are unique -- so it is more similar to `rank()` than to `row_number()` in your query.  Both of these could be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to the wonderful and clever (as always) solution given by one of the best data miners, Gordon Linoff.

I modified the second query so it leaves room for fantasy and removes the assumption that each product line has "at least 3 products" limitation!

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
WHERE p.quantityInStock IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT p2.quantityInStock
                            FROM products p2
                            WHERE p2.productline = p.productline
                            ORDER BY p2.quantityInStock DESC
                            LIMIT 3) AS T 
                           );
```

I don't know how efficient the above solution is but looks similar to the previous logic. Like Gordon suggested the solution assumes "relatively few product lines" and virtually unlimited Products.

Again, credit to Gordon and thank you.